# Long term NDVI mean from different resolution satellite imageries

Tags: resolution, ndvi

I have 10 years satellite imageries of different resolution (Landsat TM, LISS3, AWiFS and Landsat 8). My aim is to generate long term mean NDVI from that data.

Since the resolutions are not same, i couldnt able to calculate the long term NDVI mean. How can i reduce the resolution of images with respect to one reference image.

Answer (score 1):

one of the tools for doing this is [gdal_warp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html). You can force the spatial resolution of the outputs using -tr (e.g. -tr 56 56 , for your coarsest resolution).

However, you should be aware that this requires a very good calibration of your different sensors. This is very difficult to achieve, but you should at least try to have decent Top of Atmosphere reflectance (and topographic corrections if you are in a mountainous area).